# How do i remove duplicates from xml doc using linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following code and need to remove duplicate Ids and return the result as a string?

scheduledCustomerJourneysXml is a string variable containg the xml below:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(scheduledCustomerJourneysXml);


<ScheduledCustomerJourneys>
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534454" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534455" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534455" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="538020" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="538020" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="538020" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="538020" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="531228" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534457" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="526977" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="526978" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="538023" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534459" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534459" />
</ScheduledCustomerJourneys>
```

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to find duplicates and then remove those in the memory and return the string representation:

```
doc.Descendants("ScheduledCustomerJourney")
        .GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("ScheduledCustomerJourneyId").Value)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Key == string.Empty ? x : x.Skip(1))
        .Remove();

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

### Output:

```
<ScheduledCustomerJourneys>
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534454" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534455" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="538020" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="531228" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534457" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="526977" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="526978" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="538023" />
  <ScheduledCustomerJourney ScheduledCustomerJourneyId="534459" />
</ScheduledCustomerJourneys>
```

See the [working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lYlgg4)